# Google Fit API does not work in internal testing

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Google Fit API to get fitness data for a kotlin app.
But API does not work in internal testing on Google Play Developer Console.

When connecting the USB cable and install the APK directly, it will succeed, so I think that the Google API setting(Sha1 Finger print,etc) is correct.

For the part that links with the API, [the official github code](https://github.com/android/fit-samples/tree/main/StepCounterKotlin) is used as it is.
Do you have any information about my error?

````
/**
 * This enum is used to define actions that can be performed after a successful sign in to Fit.
 * One of these values is passed to the Fit sign-in, and returned in a successful callback, allowing
 * subsequent execution of the desired action.
 */
enum class FitActionRequestCode {
    SUBSCRIBE,
    READ_DATA
}

/**
 * This sample demonstrates combining the Recording API and History API of the Google Fit platform
 * to record steps, and display the daily current step count. It also demonstrates how to
 * authenticate a user with Google Play Services.
 */
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        .build()

    private val runningQOrLater =
        android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // This method sets up our custom logger, which will print all log messages to the device
        // screen, as well as to adb logcat.
        initializeLogging()

        checkPermissionsAndRun(FitActionRequestCode.SUBSCRIBE)
    }

    private fun checkPermissionsAndRun(fitActionRequestCode: FitActionRequestCode) {
        if (permissionApproved()) {
            fitSignIn(fitActionRequestCode)
        } else {
            requestRuntimePermissions(fitActionRequestCode)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the user is signed in, and if so, executes the specified function. If the user is
     * not signed in, initiates the sign in flow, specifying the post-sign in function to execute.
     *
     * @param requestCode The request code corresponding to the action to perform after sign in.
     */
    private fun fitSignIn(requestCode: FitActionRequestCode) {
        if (oAuthPermissionsApproved()) {
            performActionForRequestCode(requestCode)
        } else {
            requestCode.let {
                GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    requestCode.ordinal,
                    getGoogleAccount(), fitnessOptions
                )
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Runs the desired method, based on the specified request code. The request code is typically
     * passed to the Fit sign-in flow, and returned with the success callback. This allows the
     * caller to specify which method, post-sign-in, should be called.
     *
     * @param requestCode The code corresponding to the action to perform.
     */
    private fun performActionForRequestCode(requestCode: FitActionRequestCode) = when (requestCode) {
        FitActionRequestCode.READ_DATA -> readData()
        FitActionRequestCode.SUBSCRIBE -> subscribe()
    }

    var gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build()

    private fun oAuthPermissionsApproved() = GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(
        getGoogleAccount(),
        fitnessOptions
    )

    /**
     * Gets a Google account for use in creating the Fitness client. This is achieved by either
     * using the last signed-in account, or if necessary, prompting the user to sign in.
     * `getAccountForExtension` is recommended over `getLastSignedInAccount` as the latter can
     * return `null` if there has been no sign in before.
     */
    private fun getGoogleAccount() = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions)


    /**
     * Handles the callback from the OAuth sign in flow, executing the post sign in function
     */
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        when (resultCode) {
            RESULT_OK -> {
                val postSignInAction = FitActionRequestCode.values()[requestCode]
                postSignInAction.let {
                    performActionForRequestCode(postSignInAction)
                }
            }
            else -> oAuthErrorMsg(requestCode, resultCode)
        }
    }

    private fun oAuthErrorMsg(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int) {
        val message = """
            There was an error signing into Fit. Check the troubleshooting section of the README
            for potential issues.
            Request code was: $requestCode
            Result code was: $resultCode
        """.trimIndent()
        Log.e(TAG, message)
    }



    /** Records step data by requesting a subscription to background step data.  */
    private fun subscribe() {
        // To create a subscription, invoke the Recording API. As soon as the subscription is
        // active, fitness data will start recording.
        Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, getGoogleAccount())
            .subscribe(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!")
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.", task.exception)
                }
            }
    }

    /**
     * Reads the current daily step total, computed from midnight of the current day on the device's
     * current timezone.
     */
    private fun readData() {
        Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, getGoogleAccount())
            .readDailyTotal(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .addOnSuccessListener { dataSet ->
                val total = when {
                    dataSet.isEmpty -> 0
                    else -> dataSet.dataPoints.first().getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt()
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Total steps: $total")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem getting the step count.", e)
            }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the main; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == R.id.action_read_data) {
            fitSignIn(FitActionRequestCode.READ_DATA)
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    /** Initializes a custom log class that outputs both to in-app targets and logcat.  */
    private fun initializeLogging() {
        // Wraps Android's native log framework.
        val logWrapper = LogWrapper()
        // Using Log, front-end to the logging chain, emulates android.util.log method signatures.
        Log.setLogNode(logWrapper)
        // Filter strips out everything except the message text.
        val msgFilter = MessageOnlyLogFilter()
        logWrapper.next = msgFilter
        // On screen logging via a customized TextView.
        val logView = findViewById<View>(R.id.sample_logview) as LogView
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(logView, R.style.Log)
        logView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
        msgFilter.next = logView
        Log.i(TAG, "Ready")
    }

    private fun permissionApproved(): Boolean {
        val approved = if (runningQOrLater) {
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
            )
        } else {
            true
        }
        return approved
    }

    private fun requestRuntimePermissions(requestCode: FitActionRequestCode) {
        val shouldProvideRationale =
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
            )

        // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
        // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
        requestCode.let {
            if (shouldProvideRationale) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.")
                Snackbar.make(
                    findViewById(R.id.main_activity_view),
                    R.string.permission_rationale,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
                )
                    .setAction(R.string.ok) {
                        // Request permission
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            this,
                            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION),
                            requestCode.ordinal
                        )
                    }
                    .show()
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission")
                // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
                // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
                // previously and checked "Never ask again".
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION),
                    requestCode.ordinal
                )
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        when {
            grantResults.isEmpty() -> {
                // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request
                // is cancelled and you receive empty arrays.
                Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.")
            }
            grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
                // Permission was granted.
                val fitActionRequestCode = FitActionRequestCode.values()[requestCode]
                fitActionRequestCode.let {
                    fitSignIn(fitActionRequestCode)
                }
            }
            else -> {
                // Permission denied.

                // In this Activity we've chosen to notify the user that they
                // have rejected a core permission for the app since it makes the Activity useless.
                // We're communicating this message in a Snackbar since this is a sample app, but
                // core permissions would typically be best requested during a welcome-screen flow.

                // Additionally, it is important to remember that a permission might have been
                // rejected without asking the user for permission (device policy or "Never ask
                // again" prompts). Therefore, a user interface affordance is typically implemented
                // when permissions are denied. Otherwise, your app could appear unresponsive to
                // touches or interactions which have required permissions.

            }
        }
    }
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpQLO.png
````

Answer (score 4):

We had the exact same issue and it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. Even tho this question is over 1-year old I think it's nice to have it answered.

When you upload an APK for internal testing, it's not signed with your certificate, it's signed using a certificate issued by Google. For this reason, the SHA1 fingerprint configured for the fitness API does not match.

To overcome the issue, what you have to do is go to the developer console> internal testing > version details > downloads and download the apk from there. Once you have the apk, obtain the sha-1 fingerprint directly from it using

```
keytool -printcert -jarfile fileName.apk
```

That'll print the details of the certificate, including the SHA-1 fingerprint. Configure that fingerprint for the fitness oauth certificate and it'll work!

Remember to change this to the correct fingerprint when going to beta/production

It's nice to provide a closeup for this